# Aggregate functions with a left outer join in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, aggregate, left-join

I've been looking through related LINQ questions here trying to figure this one out, but I'm having some trouble converting a SQL query of mine to the equivalent LINQ to Entities version.

```
select companies.CommpanyName,
       job.Position,
       count(offers.jobID) As Offered,
       job.Openings,
       job.Filled
from jobs
left outer join offers on  jobs.ID = offers.JobID
join membership.dbo.individuals on jobs.UserID = individuals.ID
join membership.dbo.companies on individuals.CompanyID = companies.ID
where jobs.Hidden = 0
group by offers.JobID,
         companies.CommpanyName,
         job.Position,
         job.Openings,
         job.Filled
```

I've done left outer joins in LINQ before [similar to this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions) but I'm not sure how to combine the `count` and `group` statements with this to get the desired result:

```
    CompanyName    Position    Offered    Openings    Filled

1   Exmaple Co.    Job X       0          2           0
2   Example Co.    Job Y       4          6           3
3   Test Co.       Job Z       1          1           1
```

The query is further complicated by the fact that it needs to utilize two separate data contexts. I apologize for the lack of example code, but I'm really not sure how to start this, my LINQ-fu is still weak.

**Update:**

This is the solution I arrived at with Craig's help, had to use LINQ to Objects because of the unfortunate multiple context setup, JobWithOfferCounts is not an entity object:

```
IEnumerable<Job> t = context1.JobSet.Include("Offers").Include("Contacts").Where(j => j.Hidden == false);
IEnumerable <JobWithOfferCounts> r = (from j in t
                 join i in context2.IndividualSet on j.UserID equals i.ID
                 join c in context2.CompanySet on i.CompanyID equals c.ID
                 select new JobWithOfferCounts()
                 {
                    JobObject = j,
                    CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(c.ID),
                    CompanyName = c.HostName,
                    OfferCount = j.offers.Count(o => o.Rejected == false),
                    FilledCount = j.offers.Count(o => o.Accepted == true),
                    PendingCount = j.offers.Count(o => o.Accepted == false && o.Rejected == false)
                 });            

        return r;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see why you have `individuals` in your query, or why you `group by offers.JobID` when it (unlike `jobs.JobId`) could be null, but here's a first stab:

```
var q = from c in Context.Companies     
        from i in c.Individuals
        from j in i.Jobs
        where j.Hidden == 0
        select new 
        {
            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
            Position = j.Position,
            Offered = j.Offers.Count(),
            Openings = j.Openings,
            Filled = j.Filled
        };
```

[It's rarely correct to use `join` in LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/).

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab at it, Craig, looks promising; and for providing the link to your article.

To address your first comment, the db is designed so that the only way to tie a job to the company is through the individual that posted it (the individual data is also displayed sometimes in certain situation in the app). As for the group by, you're absolutely right about the erroneous offers.JobID

Comment: If I have a (non-ideal) situation where the individuals are in a different data context, is there still a way to do it without using a join?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that works even *with* a JOIN. You'll probably have to bring both lists into LINQ to Objects, and combine them there. "Non ideal" is putting things a bit mildly!

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, and it's pretty inefficient, luckily it's just for reporting purposes right now, so it doesn't run very often. The reason for the two different data contexts comes from having this info spread across old databases and different servers. Hopefully I'll get some updatable views of the data on the other db soon so at least I can have it in the same context.