# Left outer join in linq

Tags: c#, linq, outer-join

I have the following query but i have no idea on how to do a left outer join on table 1.

```
var query = (from r in table1
             join f in table2
                 on r.ID equals f.ID
             select new
             {     
                 r.ID, 
                 r.FirstName,
                 r.LastName,
                 FirstNameOnRecord = 
                     (f != null ? f.FirstName : string.Empty),
                 LastNameOnRecord = 
                     (f != null ? f.LastName : string.Empty),
                 NameChanged = 
                     (f != null 
                         ? (f.FirstName.CompareTo(r.FirstName) == 0 
                             && f.LastName.CompareTo(r.LastName) == 0) 
                         : false)
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: [The .NET Standard Query Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx) has been very useful to me since I started using linq a couple of years ago. The link has loads of examples and definitions (you'll want to peruse the "join" section,and specifically the GroupJoin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions) or [this](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/) examples to learn more and your case  it would be something like this-

```
var query = from r in table1
            join f in table2
            on r.ID equals f.ID into g
            from f in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {     
                r.ID
                , r.FirstName
                , r.LastName
                , FirstNameOnRecord = (f != null ? f.FirstName : string.Empty)
                , LastNameOnRecord = (f != null ? f.LastName : string.Empty)
                , NameChanged = (f != null ? (f.FirstName.CompareTo(r.FirstName) == 0 
                &&  f.LastName.CompareTo(r.LastName) == 0) : false)
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a great breakdown of the [left outer join](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/).

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [these examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)? You're probably interested in [this part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin) about Left Outer Join in Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Using lambda expression

```
db.Categories    
  .GroupJoin(
     db.Products,
     Category => Category.CategoryId,
     Product => Product.CategoryId,
     (x, y) => new { Category = x, Products = y })
  .SelectMany(
     xy => xy.Products.DefaultIfEmpty(),
     (x, y) => new { Category = x.Category, Product = y })
  .Select(s => new
  {
     CategoryName = s.Category.Name,     
     ProductName = s.Product.Name   
  })
```