# LINQ join query with multiple fields using left outer join

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have Product table and Officer table as follow:

#### Product

```
ProductID | ProductName | Officer1ID | Officer2ID | Officer3ID
--------- | ----------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------
12        | Mouse       | 123        | 124        | 125
13        | Keyboard    | 234        | 235        | 0
```

#### Officer

```
OfficerID | OfficerName 
--------- | ----------- 
123       | John       
124       | Andy    
125       | Mark
```

I need to join 3 columns (Officer1ID, Officer2ID, Officer3ID) from Product table with OfficerID in Officer table to produce result like this:

```
ProductID | ProductName | Officer1Name | Officer2Name | Officer3Name
--------- | ----------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------------
12        | Mouse       | John         | Andy         | Mark
13        | Keyboard    | Dave         | Fred         | Leon
```

This is my attempt. I know how to join 1 field, but not multiple. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
List<Product> lstProduct = GetProducts();

List<Officer> lstOfficer = GetOfficers();

var merge = from p in lstProduct
   join from o in lstOfficers on p.Officer1ID equals o.OfficerID
   select new { ProductID = p.ProductID, ProductName = p.ProductName, OfficerName = o.OfficerName };
```

**EDIT**

OfficerIDs in Product table could be 0(not exist in Officer table).

Comment: Columns called `Foo1`, `Foo2`, etc... are generally a sign that your data model is wrong.

Comment: @mark byers: some kind of relation-table should be supported instead (just to complete your comment)

Comment: Our client has various products. Different product will have different product officer, finance officer project officer assigned to take care of the product. This is the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using subquery, inspired from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions/1123051#1123051).

```
var merge = from p in lstProduct
            select new
            {
                p.ProductID,
                p.ProductName,
                Officer1Name = (from o in lstOfficer
                               where o.OfficerID == p.Officer1ID
                               select o.OfficerName).FirstOrDefault(),
                Officer1Name = (from o in lstOfficer
                               where o.OfficerID == p.Officer2ID
                               select o.OfficerName).FirstOrDefault(),
                Officer2Name = (from o in lstOfficer
                               where o.OfficerID == p.Officer3ID
                               select o.OfficerName).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Just apply the join 3 times (once for each `OfficerID`):

```
var merge = from p in lstProduct
            join o1 in lstOfficer on p.Officer1ID equals o1.OfficerID
            join o2 in lstOfficer on p.Officer2ID equals o2.OfficerID
            join o3 in lstOfficer on p.Officer3ID equals o3.OfficerID
            select new
                     {
                         ProductID = p.ProductID,
                         ProductName = p.ProductName,
                         Officer1Name = o1.OfficerName,
                         Officer2Name = o2.OfficerName,
                         Officer3Name = o3.OfficerName
                     };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is quite close to what I am looking for. I forgot to mention that some OfficerIDs in Product table are null/empty.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [multiple joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins).

You should reconsider your data model. I suggest using [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to make many to many relationship:

**Product**

```
ProductID | ProductName | ProductOfficiersID
--------- | ----------- | ---------- 
12        | Mouse       | 1        
13        | Keyboard    | 2
```

**ProductOfficiers**

```
ProductOfficiersID | ProductID | OficierId 
------------------ | --------- | -----------
1                  | 12        | 123     
1                  | 12        | 124  
1                  | 12        | 125
2                  | 13        | 234
...
```

**Officer**
...