# Return Only Child Entity Linq Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

Given something like:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

// There is no reference to the parent in the object model
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

is it possible to load *only* a child matching a particular condition, for a given Parent ID, without also loading the parent entity?

I have [seen solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7768436/141172) that use projection to load the parent *and* zero or more children matching a condition.

Comment: How does your data model work if a child has no idea what it's parent is?

Comment: why not `db.Childs.Where(c => c.MyProperty == "something")`?

Comment: @CuongLe: That does not filter on the parent ID.

Comment: @AlastairPitts: The data model knows, but the object model does not.  EF creates a column to represent the relationship in the child table, but does not expose it to the object model unless the parent object is expressly included as a property of the child object.

Comment: @EricJ. Ah. That makes sense, also makes it hard. Any specific reason the parent is not included as a property of the child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it; it puts the conditions you want on both the parent and child, but selects only the child.

```
from parent in db.Parents
from child in parent.Children
where parent.Id = 4711 &&
      child.MyProperty == "olle"
select child;
```