# Combining LINQ Queries to reduce database calls

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 2 queries that work, I was hoping to combine them to reduce the database calls.

```
                var locations = from l in db.Locations
                                where l.LocationID.Equals(TagID)
                                select l;
```

I do the above because I need l.Name, but is there a way to take the above results and put them into the query below?

```
                articles = from a in db.Articles
                               where
                               (
                               from l in a.Locations
                               where l.LocationID.Equals(TagID)
                               select l
                               ).Any()
                               select a;
```

Will I actually be reducing any database calls here?

Comment: Can you turn that into a join? Or is it many locations per tag ID?

Comment: TagID will be only a single location, A join sounds like the right way, I'm just not skilled enough in Linq to make it happen!

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit complicated because `Locations` appears to be a multi-value property of `Articles` and you want to only load the correct one. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7768436/243245) to a similar question you need to use a select to return them separately in one go so e.g.

```
var articles = from a in db.Articles
               select new {
                   Article = a,
                   Location = a.Locations.Where(l => l.LocationId == TagId)
               };
```

---

First failed attempt using `join`:

```
var articlesAndLocations = from a in db.Articles
                           join l in a.Locations
                             on l.LocationID equals TagID
                           select new { Article = a, Location = l };
```

(I usually use the other LINQ syntax though so apologies if I've done something stupid there.)

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to work - I can an error on the 'a' on the second line, that "The name 'a' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Right, sorry, I was guessing there :-/ Second try, something closer to the linked answer, although I'm less confident this will be a single DB hit. If that fails I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the `Include()` method here to pull in the locations which are associated with each article, then select both the article and location object? or the properties you need from each.

The include method will ensure that you don't need to dip into the db twice, but will allow you to access properties on related entities.

You would need to use a `contains` method on an IEnumerable I believe, something like this:

```
var tagIdList = new List() { TagID };

var articles = from a in db.Articles.Include("Locations")
           where tagIdList.Contains(from l in a.Locations select l.LocationID)
           select new { a, a.Locations.Name };
```

(Untested)

Comment: Looks promising, but I get an error on Locations.LocationID on the second line: System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<xxx.Models.Location>' does not contain a definition for 'LocationID' and no extension method 'LocationID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<xxx.Models.Location>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah right, in that case you need to slim down your locations to a single record, or use a contains statement.