# the grid shows TypeProducts in blank , i dont want to use anonymous type like new{}

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

```
 public class GridData
    {
        public static IList gridDatos()
        {
            {
                using (EnterpriseEntities dbcontext = new EnterpriseEntities())
                {
                       var _products = dbcontext.Products.
                        Include(c => c.TypeProducts).ToList();
                    return _products;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: You're probably going to get hammered for a poorly formed question. Are you asking how to do a projection with your child collection? Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753039/entity-framework-querying-child-entities

Comment: I dont want to grab specific data i want to grab all products data related with all typeproducts data

Answer (score 0):

You  forgot to specify what type of `IList` you are returning in your return type part of the method.

```
public static IList<Product> gridDatos()
{
    using (var dbcontext = new EnterpriseEntities())
    {
         var _products = dbcontext.Products.
                        Include(c => c.TypeProducts).ToList();
         return _products;
    }
}
```

Or you have DTO's / POCCO's/ ViewModels , You can do a projection to that in your LINQ expression to make sure that you are executing only one query againist your db. If not, If you are iterating over the Product collection in your razor view and trying to access a Navgation property of a different type, It will execute a query again for each unique record there. Read more about deferred execution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921262/is-deferred-execution-in-asp-net-mvc-view-a-very-bad-thing/33921573#33921573).

So let's say you have a DTO like this

```
public class ProductDto
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Name {set;get;}
  public List<TypeProductDto> Types {set;get;}
}           
public class TypeProductDto 
{
  public class string TypeName {set;get; }
}
```

So in your LINQ expression, project the results to our new DTO's

```
public static List<ProductDto> GetProducts()
{
    using (var dbcontext = new EnterpriseEntities())
    {
         var _products = dbcontext.Products.
                        Select(x=> new ProductDto
                           {  Id =x.Id, 
                              Name =x.Name,
                              Types= x.TypeProducts
                                       .Select(t=>new TypeProductDto
                                                  { Name =x.Name})
                           }).ToList();
         return _products;
    }
}
```

This will execute only a single query and map the results to the DTO.

Comment: The entity or complex type 'DbContext.TypeProducts' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.