# Entity Framework: Filter grandchildren of a parent object in the database in a single database call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Very similar to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753039/entity-framework-querying-child-entities) but I want to filter on a grandchild of the parent object i.e. do something similar to

```
db.Parents
  .Where(p => p.Age > 70)
  .Include(p => p.Children.GrandChildren)
  .Where(p => p.GrandChildren.Any(gc => gc.Age >= 5))
```

The marked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7768436/955950) works correctly but how to extend it for my scenario?
Also I would like to make just one database call, is this possible with EF?

I don't know if it makes a difference but my children and grandchildren properties are collections.

I currently have code similar to what's below, which does not work!

```
 var query = this.dbContext.Parent.AsNoTracking()
              .Where(p => p.Age > 70)
              .Select(p=> new
              {
                  Parent = p,
                  FirstChild = p.FirstChild,
                  ChildrenCollection = p.ChildrenCollection
                  GrandChildrenCollection = p.ChildrenCollection.SelectMany(cc => cc.GrandChildren)                    
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

It fails with an InvalidOperationException, message "Additional information: Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type 'GrandChildren' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet."

Comment: Is GrandChildren entity mapped correctly to table name? Have you linked Parent-Children-GrandChildren tables correctly?

Comment: @Logar314159 Yes, the GrandChildren entity is mapped correctly to the tablename.

Comment: @Logar314159 In calls where I don't need to filter on the grandchildren, the works correctly, so I am pretty certain the tables are linked correctly via primary keys  

    `var query = this.dbContext.Parent.Where(p => p.Age > 70)
                .Include(bd => bd.ChildrenCollection.Select(og => og.ChildrenCollection.Select(bo => bo.OrderBroker)))
                .Include(bd => bd.FirstChild);  

var parentFound = query.FirstOrDefault();  
return parentFound;`