# datatables left join c#

Tags: c#, datatable, left-join

Let T1 and T2 are DataTables with following fields

T1(CustID, ColX, ColY)

T2(CustID, ColZ)

I need to perform Left join on CustID

How this can be done in C# code in a simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: same question ? i dont understand why you post it again here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-in-datatable-in-c-sharp

Comment: Your question is not clear. Joining tables is about SQL, not about C#. Databases can be accessed in many ways. Here is just one [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.90).aspx) described on MSDN.

Comment: The OP is asking about left join.  The link @rahularyansharma posted was for an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to do this.  Here is the pseudocode for a left join on two data collections:

```
T1.rows.Select(leftRow=>new{
CustID = leftRow.CustID
ColX = leftRow.ColX
ColY = leftRow.ColY
ColZ = T2.Select(rightRow=>rightRow.ColZ).Where(rightRow=>rightRow.CustID == leftRow.CustID).FirstOrDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you might be driving at the .NET concept of [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx).  If that's the case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions) talks about Left Join using Linq.

If not, just think about what a left join is and create a type that matches what you want (CustID, ColX, ColY, ColZ) where ColZ is nullable and populate it according to rules of left join.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query for the left outer join

```
 var query = from t_1 in T1 
                        join t_2 in T2 on t_1.CustID equals t2.CustID into gj
                        from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { x= t_1.ColX,y=t_2.ColY};
```