# How to get Left outer join in Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables in my database that look like that:

Customer:

```
C_ID  city
--------------
1     Dhaka
2     New york
3     London
```

Personal_Info:

```
P_ID  C_ID  Field       value
-------------------------------
1     1     First Name  Nasir
2     1     Last Name   Uddin
3     2     First Name  Jon
4     3     First Name  Lee
```

I need a select result like that:

**C_ID = '1':**

```
C_ID  Name (First Name + Last Name)  City
------------------------------------------
1     Nasir Uddin                    Dhaka
```

**C_ID = '2':**

```
C_ID  Name (First Name + Last Name)  City
---------------------------------------------
2     Jon                            New york
```

How would the corresponding Linq query look like?

Thanks
Nahid

Comment: See the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions

Comment: After almost 50 questions you should start using the code block button in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following a previous answer such as [Linq to Sql: Multiple left outer joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267488/linq-to-sql-multiple-left-outer-joins) you can see the structure for solving this eg something like:

```
var result = from customer in customers  
                   from personalFirst in personal  
                       .Where(pf => pf.Field == "First Name" && pf.C_ID == customer.C_ID)  
                       .DefaultIfEmpty() 
                   from personalLast in personal  
                       .Where(pl => pl.Field == "Last Name" && pl.C_ID == customer.C_ID)  
                       .DefaultIfEmpty()  
                    where customer.C_ID == 2  
                    select new { customer.C_ID, Name = (personalFirst != null ? personalFirst.Value : "") + " " + (personalLast != null ? personalLast.Value : "") };
```

Obviously if you want all records then remove the restriction on C_ID = 2

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why? The LINQ works so therefore answers the question. If there's a better approach (and there may be) then its worth showing