# LINQ query concept

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this requirement of a query I need.

Here is the data I have in a table:

```
row1  row2
A     B
A     C
A     D
A     E
E     B
E     C
E     A
E     D
```

I want all rows

```
where row1 IN ('A', 'E')
```

But I don't want the row ***where row1 = E and row2 = A***.

I think in straight SQL I could do an aliased table like ***SELECT....AS Table1*** and then select only the rows where **row2** was not found in **Table1**, but I'm not sure how to go about this in LINQ.

Any ideas ?

EDIT: Sorry for the ambiguity of my question, but I do not know in advance the criteria **where row1 in ('A', 'E')**. Basically if I have retrieved a record (**record1**) with a specific value in **row1**, if I find that same specific value in **row2** in another record (**record2**), I do not want **record2**.

Comment: `.Where((obj => obj.row1 == "E" && obj.row2 != "A") || (obj => obj.row1 == "A" && obj.row2 != "E")` This? Your requirements aren't quite clear.

Comment: why cannot you add `NOT (row1 = 'E' and row2 = 'A')` ?

Comment: Use a LINQ-left-join onto the same table and look for nulls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions . This question changed significantly between edits

Comment: Sorry, vcsjones, I have added more details in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Still not entirely clear after your update but I think this gets you on the right track:

```
var rows = new[] {
Tuple.Create("A", "B"),
Tuple.Create("A", "C"),
Tuple.Create("A", "D"),
Tuple.Create("A", "E"),
Tuple.Create("E", "B"),
Tuple.Create("E", "C"),
Tuple.Create("E", "A"),
Tuple.Create("E", "D"),
};
var reference = Tuple.Create("A", "E");

var result = rows.Where(r => (r.Item1 == reference.Item1 || r.Item1 == reference.Item2)
                          && r.Item2 != reference.Item1
                          && r.Item1 != reference.Item2);
```

After your update I'm not sure whether or not the last condition should be included. Presently it returns:

```
Item1 Item2 
A     B 
A     C 
A     D 
A     E
```

Maybe you can show the desired output if this still misses the mark.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you want to create a PIVOT query.

So with your input you want to get an output of the form

Key - Value

A - B,C,D,E

B - B,C,A,D

Where Key is of type string and Value is of type IEnumerable

In that case you want: -

```
var output = allRows.ToLookup(x => x.row1, x => x.row2);
```