# Linq To SQL LEFT JOIN (OR Statement)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to rewrite this simple MS SQL Query in Linq To SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.Table1ID OR T1.FirstName = T2.FirstName
```

How do I rewrite this in Linq To SQL?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count

Comment: It is not duplicate, look there is only one condition in join

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx?

Comment: and what :) My question is about another theme

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1122942/150342  [LINQ to SQL - Left Outer Join with multiple join conditions] then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, although I don't know how well Linq-to-SQL will translate it:

```
from t1 in ctx.Table1
from t2 in ctx.Table2
              .Where(t => t1.ID == t.Table1ID ||
                          t1.FirstName == t.Firstname)
              .DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {t1, t2}
```

Comment: Can you mix Linq lambda with the regular Linq queries? That's pretty cool stuff. Although my brain hurts looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done because I don't think you can do the OR part of the join. The way you do joins in L2S would be (roughly)

```
join .. on
new {
    T1.ID,
    T1.FirstName
} equals new {
    T2.Table1ID,
    T2.FirstName
}
```

but that would match both.

Only thing I can think you could do would be to do some sort of subquery in there. But that's probably not what you're looking for. Sklivvz's suggestion may be the best one.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inner join.

```
from t1 in ctx.Table1
from t2 in ctx.Table2
where t1.ID == t2.Table1ID ||
      t1.FirstName == t2.Firstname
select t1
```

To get a left join it looks like you use `DefaultIfEmpty()`, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx).

```
from t1 in ctx.Table1
from t2 in ctx.Table2.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t1.ID == t2.Table1ID ||
      t1.FirstName == t2.Firstname
select t1
```

Comment: I think that would result in an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: It is Cross Join, I tested it