# Linq full outer join with NULL records C# from datatables

Tags: c#, linq

Please can someone help? I need to return a table on Extn_In_Call_Records = Extn_Number and if either side does not match still return a calue just like a SQL Full Outer join. I have spent hours looking at this but cant get it to work!! I can get the code to work below if I remove the union but then it only returns matched results.  The Datatable is being populated from MYSQL. Any help woud be great.

```
            //Full Table
        DataTable fullext = new DataTable();
        fullext.Columns.Add("Extn_In_Call_Records", typeof(string));
        fullext.Columns.Add("Total_Calls", typeof(int));
        fullext.Columns.Add("Extn_Number", typeof(string));
        fullext.Columns.Add("Phys_Switch_Name", typeof(string));


        //End Full Table


        try
         {

            //Full Result


             var result = from callrc in callrecdt.AsEnumerable()
                          join physex in physextns.AsEnumerable()
                          on callrc["Extn_In_Call_Records"] equals physex["Extn_Number"]
                           .Union
                          from physex in physextns.AsEnumerable()
                          join callrc in callrecdt.AsEnumerable()
                          on physex["Extn_Number"] equals callrc["Extn_In_Call_Records"] 



                          select fullext.LoadDataRow(new object[] {
                       callrc["Extn_In_Call_Records"],
                       callrc["Total_Calls"],
                       physex["Extn_Number"] == null ? "" : physex["Extn_Number"],
                       physex["Phys_Switch_Name"] == null ? "" : physex["Phys_Switch_Name"]
                       }, false);
             result.CopyToDataTable();
             fullresult.DataSource = fullext;
```

Result to see

```
Extn_In_Call_Records    Total_Calls   Extn_Number      Phys_Switch_Name
null                    20                0                Hospital
null                    310               1                Hospital
4                       132               4                Hospital
2004                    null                null           Hospital
2006                    2               2006           Hospital
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions?rq=1 (for the general "outer" concept in LINQ) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Per [LINQ - Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join), the easiest way to perform a full outer join is to union two left joins. A left-join in LINQ (using the extension method syntax) takes the form:

```
var leftJoined = from left in lefts
                 join right in rights
                   on left.Key equals right.Key
                 into temp
                 from newRight in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(/* default value for right */)
                 select new
                 {
                     /* use left and newRight to construct the joined object */
                 }
```

In your case, you want to do:

```
// initialize some default elements to use later if
// they're of the same type then a single default is fine
var defaultPhysex = new {...};
var defaultCallrc = new {...};

var left = from callrc in callrecdt.AsEnumerable()
           join physex in physextns.AsEnumerable()
             on callrc["Extn_In_Call_Records"] equals physx["Extn_Number"]
           into temp
           from physex in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultPhysex)
           select new 
           {
               // callrc is accessible here, as is the new physex
               Field1 = ...,
               Field2 = ...,
           }

var right = from physex in physextns.AsEnumerable()
            join callrc in callrecdt.AsEnumerable()
              on callrc["Extn_In_Call_Records"] equals physx["Extn_Number"]
            into temp
            from callrc in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultCallrc)
            select new 
            {
                // physex is accessible here, as is the new callrc
                Field1 = ...,
                Field2 = ...,
            }

var union = left.Union(right);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this but still struggling to get it working... Ao any help would be great.              DataTable physextns = new DataTable(); 
            extnlkp.Fill(physextns);
            //Table Format Below
   //("Company_Name")
            //("Phys_Switch_Name")
            //("Extn_Number")

            DataTable callrecdt = new DataTable();
            callrec.Fill(callrecdt);
            //Table Format Below
   //("Switch_Name");
            //("Extn_In_Call_Records");
            //("Total_Calls");
            //("Talk_Time");
            //("Total_Cost");