# ef core left join with "in" conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

i have many ids of persons that i want see group is Assigned to this person،
i have sql query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM cor.[Group] AS g 
LEFT JOIN cor.PersonGroup AS pg ON 
g.Id=pg.GroupId  AND 
pg.PersonId IN (1,2)
```

and i want to give linq query for this
i write this linq query

```
from g in _context.Groups join
                     pg in _context.PersonGroups.Where(pp =>personIds.Contains( pp.PersonId))
                    on g.Id equals pg.GroupId
```

But this is different from what I want

Comment: @john my question for "in" condition on left join

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. Perhaps you could edit your question to make that clearer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL - Left Outer Join with multiple join conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions)

Comment: @SᴇM It seems OP's problem is with the "in" condition.

Comment: @Mohammadhossein what is your exact problem with `in` condition?

Comment: @SᴇM yes , i problem with "in"

Comment: @Mohammadhossein What problem?

Comment: @SᴇM with this linq quey , generated two nested select , but i want one select

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var persons = from grp in _context.Groups
              join pg in _context.PersonGroups on grp.Id equals pg.GroupId
              where personIds.Contains(pg.PersonId)
              select pg;
```