# LINQ query join to get entries for left table where right table has no matching records

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.1

So the equivalent of this query:

```
select * from car
  left join parts ON car.Id = parts.carId
  where parts.MemberId = 1
```

is this, in EntityFrameworkCore LINQ , using an IQueryable which has already selected `car.Include(x => x.parts)`:

```
queryable = queryable.Where(x => 
  x.parts.Select(y => y.MemberId).Contains(1);
```

But how can I convert the following SQL to LINQ, so that it includes rows from the left `car` table that have no respective `MemberId` entries in the `parts` table?

```
select * from car
  left join parts ON car.Id = parts.CarId and parts.MemberId = 1
```

Models:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class Parts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Car { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what Linq provider you're executing your IQueryable against, e.g. Entity Framework

Comment: updated q to include EF core

Comment: LINQ Query is built from Model. Show your classes and navigation properties.

Comment: This is just a basic left outer join. It should be answered in several of the related questions, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions?rq=1

Comment: Is it a basic left outer join? Because when I run the first query in SQL with `left outer join` I don't get the unmatched entries from the left table, it only brings matched entries.

Comment: Yes, the second query is a left outer join with two conditions in the ON clause. One condition in the ON clause and another in the WHERE clause behaves differently, but that is beside the point. See the linked question for how to handle multiple join conditions in ON clause with Linq

Comment: Thanks. That link shows it's a real fanny on, I'm just breaking it into two separate lines, not only is that GroupJoin syntax OTT it didn't actually give me the default empty as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [filtered `Include`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618096/filtering-on-include-in-ef-core/61147681#61147681) does exactly what you want:

```cs
var cars = context.Cars
    .Include(c => c.Parts.Where(p => p.MemberId == 1));
```

This doesn't generate the shorter join statement with a composite condition, but an outer join to a filtered subquery on `Parts`, to the same effect.

Comment: Yup, this is correct! But I forgot to state in my question that I'm using 2.1 for this project :(

Comment: Ah, too bad, it requires ef-core 5+ (as you'll probably realize). For lower versions there's a work-around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801205/861716

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
queryable = queryable.Include(x => x.parts).Where(x => 
  x.parts.Any(y => y.MemberId == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Nope, this is giving me less than I want - this is giving me ONLY matching records for MemberId, I want all of those AND records from `Car` where there are no matching entries for `Parts`

Answer (score 0):

```
queryable = queryable
    .Where(x => x.parts.Select(y => y.MemberId).Contains(1) || !x.parts.Any());
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - it's giving me null entries as expected but also where MemberId != 1