# Filtered left joins in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out how to translate the following SQL query into an Entity Framework Linq Query.

```
int otherFkId = 111;
int anotherFkId = 222;

var query = SELECT * 
FROM dbContext.table1 a
LEFT JOIN dbContext.table2 b 
    ON a.id = b.fkId
    AND b.otherFk = otherFkId
WHERE a.anotherFk = anotherFkId;

var results = query.ToList();
```

The error I receive is the the generic "The LINQ expression could not be translated". Any Ideas?

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122942/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-multiple-join-conditions) "works"... But ONLY if I manually inject the value, like so:

```
int anotherFkId = 222;

var query = SELECT * 
FROM dbContext.table1 a
LEFT JOIN dbContext.table2 b 
    ON a.id = b.fkId
    AND b.otherFk = 111
WHERE a.anotherFk = anotherFkId;

var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I do not see LINQ query here. What is the question?